# Yii2: How to get checkox's value from controller

Tags: model-view-controller, checkbox, yii2

I need to get the value of a checkbox called Password using the Yii2 Framework, in the controller.

In my _form.php I define the checkbox:

```
<?= Html::checkbox('password', false, $options = ['label' => 'Reset password']) ?>
```

In my UserController.php I have the actionUpdate function:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
     if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        echo '<pre>';
        echo Yii::$app->request->post()['password'];
        echo '</pre>';
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I always get the value **1** instead of **true** or **false**.

Comment: I'm no php expert and certainly not one for Yii, but it looks to me as if you may be getting the array of IDs of all selected checkboxes there. Can you double check that (if your selected checkbox's ID is 1, and if that's why you're receiving it)?

Comment: Yii checkbox return 1 for true(checked) and 0 for false

Comment: @YasinPatel. Write your comment as an answer so I can selected as the accepted answer.

Comment: @RobySottini, i have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkbox return 1 for true(checked) and return 0 for false(not checked).

You can check in controller as below

```
if(isset($model->password) && $model->password =="1") //check box is checked
{
     // code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there is error in your code, it should be:

```
<?= Html::checkbox('password', false, ['label' => 'Reset password']) ?>
```

This checkbox generates `1` when checked by default. If you want to send `0` when checkbox is not selected you must add:

```
<?= Html::checkbox('password', false, ['label' => 'Reset password', 'uncheck' => 0]) ?>
```